# EntityFramework how to Override properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I've just started using EF in VS2010. That thing is just amazin'.

I frankly can't understand something. For example I have EntityType with property, they generated from database structure. 
Now, I have to simply override that property in my code. I don't need to save value of the property back into DB, but everytime when it gets read from DB it should be substituted with run-time calculated value.

Of course I can create derived class based on my EntityType but I've tried and found kinda difficulties, I'm not sure this is kinda right way to do. Anyway even when I try to change the  whole EntityType to Abstract, damn Visual Studio doesn't want to validate that and says something like:

"Error 2078: The EntityType 'AssetsModel.Asset' is Abstract and can be mapped only using IsTypeOf."
"Error 2063: At least one property must be mapped in the set mapping for 'Assets'"

What the hell is this suppose to mean I dunno..

Any ideas?

Comment: "I've tried and found kinda difficulties, " what does that mean?

Comment: Need to see a some code, I don't uderstand what you want

Comment: What's wrong with using partial classes and creating a new ReadOnly property to calculate the value?

Comment: Wow... I haven't thought about it. That exactly what I wanted. Thank thank you, thank you, thank you...

Comment: Willbt that is the answer! So why not post it as one so I can up vote it accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach would be to use Partial Classes and then create a new ReadOnly property to calculate the value in the getter.